# Zabbix Agent installation on OpenSuse 13.2 with yum fails

Tags: yum, zabbix, opensuse

when installing Zabbix v3.4 I get the following error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1v0d.jpg

Looks like an error in the yum repository. Do you have any suggestions for solutions or something similar?

Best regards

Comment: It might be useful to include the error as a text here for easier searching. As for the installation, any reason why are you using `yum` instead of the native `zypper` package management tool?

Comment: I´ll get an Zypper Repo error as well ...

Comment: Please add those errors here.

Comment: @diethermohose How did you add Zabbix repository?

Comment: the zypper repo like this: sudo zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/monitoring/openSUSE_13.2/server:monitoring.repo

Comment: and the yum repo like this: sudo rpm -ivh http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.4/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.4-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, [there](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/monitoring/openSUSE_13.2/x86_64/) is just 2.2 version of Zabbix (agent, server, proxy, etc.) in that repository.

It seems Zabbix 2.2 (LTS) is the latest version supported by OpenSUSE using its repositories.

By the way, you can install older versions of Zabbix-agent (like 2.2) sending data correctly to newer server/proxy versions (like 3.0 or even 3.2).
I think the major item you will miss with using zabbix-agent older than 3.X is encryption. Other major features work very good.

Comment: Is there any way to get Zabbix Agent 3.4 on OpenSUSE using official repositories?

Comment: Apparently not. You have to compile it or use older version.

Comment: Alright okay. But how does the "compiling" works? Do you talk about: dkkg-buildpackage etc.? Or do you mean something different?

Comment: Zabbix manual covers installation from the sources: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/installation/install .